# Oracle Ebusiness suite integration with IDE . Server is Apache Jserv

Tags: eclipse, oracle

I am trying to configure Eclipse  IDE for integration with the Oracle E-business suite. I have the server as Apache JServ . How do I debug the jsp files remotely pertaining to Oracle E-business Istore suite/ 
Any advice or guidance is higly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the appropriate version of Eclipse. In particular, you need "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". Otherwise, you will not have access to app server integration. Then create a Dynamic Web Project, specify that you are targetting Apache during project creation. Once created, right click on a jsp file you want to run and select "run as->run on server" or the debug equivalent.

Comment: But the jsp files have java files integrated in them as import statements. how do i set the classpath so that i do not get compile errors off the jsp files?

Comment: You need to configure your Build Path correctly under project properties. Make sure that your java source directory is correctly identified as a source folder in build path. Make sure that any external libraries are included.